# User password field is empty

Tags: password

Note: actually, the described situation is on a local environment. I'd like to know what happens if it goes live with this setting.

I've installed a plugin and it has reset all the password in the WP database, so now all passwords for existing users are empty. I've generated a new password for my personal user. About other users, can I leave the password blank in the database or is it dangerous? I've noticed that if I try to login with an empty password the login is impossible in wordpress.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I still wouldn't recommend this because it is probably exploitable somehow...

Technically assuming all the right hooks and functions are called, a user should not be able to login if supplying a blank password even if the `user_pass` field in the database is empty.

#### Why...?

When you try to login using the form as seen on `/wp-login./php`, WordPress will call `wp_authenticate_username_password()` which is hooked onto the `authenticate` action.

`wp_authenticate_username_password()` checks to see if the submitted `$password` is not empty. If it is empty, it will raise an instance of `WP_Error` and the login request will be rejected.

The same applies anywhere you try to login from, be it a custom login form or not, assuming the correct hooks or functions are called, e.g. `authenticate` or `wp_authenticate_username_password()`.

Now even if you make it to the `wp_check_password()` point of `wp_authenticate_username_password()`, an empty password still generates a hash value when ran through `md5()`, e.g. `md5('') //d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e`.

So what happens when we enter the `wp_check_password()` function is that the following logic is ran...

Source: `wp-includes/pluggable.php`

```
function wp_check_password($password, $hash, $user_id = '') {
    global $wp_hasher;

//note that...
//$password  = '' and $hash (from db) = ''

// If the hash is still md5...
if ( strlen($hash) <= 32 ) {
    $check = hash_equals( $hash, md5( $password ) ); // <- $check will return false, because the $hash is empty and does not match the hash of md5($password)

    if ( $check && $user_id ) {
        // Rehash using new hash.
        wp_set_password($password, $user_id);
        $hash = wp_hash_password($password);
    }

    /**
     * Filter whether the plaintext password matches the encrypted password.
     *
     * @since 2.5.0
     *
     * @param bool   $check    Whether the passwords match.
     * @param string $password The plaintext password.
     * @param string $hash     The hashed password.
     * @param int    $user_id  User ID.
     */
    return apply_filters( 'check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id );
}


// If the stored hash is longer than an MD5, presume the
// new style phpass portable hash.
if ( empty($wp_hasher) ) {
    require_once( ABSPATH . WPINC . '/class-phpass.php');
    // By default, use the portable hash from phpass
    $wp_hasher = new PasswordHash(8, true);
}

$check = $wp_hasher->CheckPassword($password, $hash);

/** This filter is documented in wp-includes/pluggable.php */
return apply_filters( 'check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id );
```

}

Ok so once we hit:

```
if ( strlen($hash) <= 32 ) {
    $check = hash_equals( $hash, md5( $password ) );
```

`$check` will return false because the value of `$hash` is an empty string and the value of `md5($password)` which is essentially `md5('')` is `d41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e` as I mentioned above.

Therefore login attempt will be rejected.

So in theory you are safe unless some malicious code hooks onto:

`return apply_filters( 'check_password', $check, $password, $hash, $user_id );`

...and returns `true`. But anyone could do that under normal circumstances where proper password hashes do exist in the database.

#### Recommendation:

Leaving `user_pass` field in database empty and void of hashes is sloppy and bad practice.

Assumming someone knew that all the passwords in the database were blank and wanted to screw you over, they'd be half-way there in doing so. All they need to do is find a way to exploit the system.

Seeing as it is unlikely that you have audited every piece of internal core code as well as code from plugins and likely your theme, you don't know when or if blank passwords will come back to bite you in the ass because of some edge-case zero day exploit that is introduced.

Instead...

```
//you can use get_users() if you prefer instead of $wpdb directly...
//this is just a one time operation.. don't forget to exclude those
//users whom you do not wish to reset a password for, e.g. yourself

global $wpdb;

$users = $wpdb->get_col("SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->prefix}users WHERE 1 = 1");

foreach ($users as $user_id) {
    wp_set_password(wp_generate_password(), $user_id);
}
```

...do yourself a favor and set passwords for all users and let the user reset the password or generate an email with a password reset link.